# Favicon icon not showing in bookmark toolbar on Mozilla browser

Tags: html, css, caching, mozilla

Favicon icon not showing in bookmark toolbar on Mozilla browser

here is the code

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /> 
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png">
  <link rel="alternate" rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">`. Other reason can be caching

Answer (score 0):

at first [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[DEL] for clear cache and then restart Firefox

for next step

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://yourdomain.com/images/favicon.ico?version=1" />
```

put favicon in the root of the web server and called favicon.ico.

Note that in recent versions of Firefox the favicon is only displayed on the tab icon and bookmark, not in the address bar icon.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I used a process for specifically creating an SVG favicon instead of using the general process that may be used on SVG, PNG, JPG, etc file types.

You seem to be using a favicon generator package on some online generator like [here](https://realfavicongenerator.net/).

Click first on the blue button at the top right of this page, entitled **Select Your Favicon Image**.

(**DO NOT** click on either of the 2 buttons below this, i.e. those entitled **Demo With A Random Image** or **Create A SVG Favicon**. The latter button does not generate a favicon that will show on your bookmarks toolbar icons although it does show on the web page tabs. The blue button process works for SVG favicons too.)

After clicking on the blue button you next navigate via your file system to the image you want to use, e.g. a website logo image, say logo.svg

After some churning, an options page opens. If your favicon is reasonably square in aspect and if it has a transparent background, you may accept default values for these configurations. At the bottom of the page click on a blue button, **Generate Your Favicons & HTML Code**

After more churning a new page is presented, entitled **Install Your Favicon**.

Copy and paste the displayed HTML code fragment after the last entry of your index page's .
Then place the image and other files in the root of your website, i.e. the same folder holding the index.html file.

Now you need to first test out your website files locally on your browser.
Open the index.html page of the website and drag the bookmark to your bookmarks folder.

The browser needs refreshing, closing and - if it doesn't clear data automatically on closing - cache + cookies clearing. Then reopen the browser on your website's bookmark. Refresh the site from the bookmarks folder once or twice. The favicon should now show on your bookmarks toolbar.

FTP all affected files in your website to the web server and repeat the previous process for the live website.